# How can I update executor time?

Tags: java, schedule, executor

I am working on executorService in Java. If the time is not out, the executor delay should be updated and the older one should be deleted.

```
Duration timeFromLast = Duration.between(this.lastTime, LocalDateTime.now());
Duration check = Duration.ofMillis(100);
Duration durationTillCheck = check.minus(timeFromLast);
if(durationTillCheck.toMillis() < 0)
{
    if(!executor.isShutdown())
    {
        executor.shutdownNow();
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }
    executor.schedule(Task, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

But sometime there is an error like "caused by ClosedByInterruptException". How can I properly do this task?

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I want to recreate new scheduler but olders must be cancel out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClosedByInterruptException` happens when you interrupt a task that is blocked in an I/O request.  In this case, it will be happening *because* you are calling `shutdownNow` on the executor.  (Calling `shutdownNow` is specified to call `Thread.interrupt()` on all of the executor's worker threads that are still doing something.)

So ...

- If you don't want the exceptions, you shouldn't call `shutdownNow`.  Instead, call `shutdown` and let the executor continue the current `Task` until it is completed.
- If you want the task to stop NOW, then call `shutdownNow` as you are currently doing, and recode the `Task` object so that it will *cope* with being interrupted.  For instance, the `Task` would need to deal with that exception ... in an appropriate way.

---

Given that you definitely do want the task to stop NOW ... the problem is not in the code that you have shown us.  The problem is in the code of the `Task` which is not properly dealing with the consequences of interruption.  But we can tell you how to fix the `Task` code without seeing it.